# Making a Map for my extended Panes (key) to Frame titles (values)

Tags: java, swing, dictionary, jpanel

I want my frame to change title when I change the the pane:

```
public void changePane(JPanel myNewPane){
    myGui.getContentPane().removeAll();
    myGui.getContentPane().add(myNewPane);
--->myGui.setTitle("Blah");
    myGui.pack();
}
```

Except I want to change the value of `"Blah"` using the input `myNewPane` as a key to the value in a map, as such I have:

```
    private Map<? extends JPanel,String> PanelNames = new HashMap<? extends JPanel, String>();
```

Except, here in Eclipse, `HashMap` is red underlined with the error *"Cannot instantiate the type HashMap"*

Where I try to add my panes and strings as keys and values, like so:

```
public void setPanelNames(Map<? extends JPanel,String> panelNames) {
    PanelNames.put(myTopManagerPane, "Main Manager Page");
    PanelNames.put(myPlayerManagerPane, "Player Manager Page");
    PanelNames.put(myGameManagerPane, "Game Manager Page");
}
```

Here `put` is red underlined; My error here is *"The method put(capture#2-of ? extends JPanel, String) in the type Map is not applicable for the arguments (TopManagerPane, String)"*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you need `? extends JPanel` instead of simply `JPanel`?

Comment: `myTopManagerPane` etc are all extensions of JPanel.

Comment: So having `JPanel` will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a `HashMap` using generics wild cards. You need to specify a concrete type instead.

Remove the `? extends` from your definitions and it should work:

```
private Map<JPanel,String> PanelNames = new HashMap<JPanel, String>();

public void setPanelNames(Map<JPanel,String> panelNames) {
  ...
}
```

Note that `Map<? extends JPanel, String>` means that you accept any map that uses a key of type `JPanel` or a subclass (e.g. `MyPanel` if it extends `JPanel`). However, the actual instance which you create when calling `new HashMap<...>()` needs to know whether any `JPanel` or only `MyPanel` instances are allowed, hence you need to use `new HashMap<JPanel, String>()` here. The map then knows that the keys are `JPanels` and can't know more about the type (it doesn't matter in that case).

In the method parameter, using `? extends JPanel` means that you could pass a `Map<JPanel, String>` or a `Map<MyPanel, String>` but the compiler won't let you add panels to the map, since it doesn't know whether that's allowed or not - adding `JPanels` to a `Map<MyPanel, String>` is illegal.

Comment: But, as I failed to point out `myTopManagerPane` is not a JPanel, it just extends it....I've just done this though, and it seems to have worked.

Comment: @Pureferret see my added info. If all the panels you want to add have the same class, then you can use that class as the key as well.

Comment: They aren't the same class, I'm considering making them the same class though... Even though they are quite different.

Comment: @Pureferret in that case (the classes being different) there's no way around using the most specialized common base class, I assume this would be `JPanel` in your case. Alternatively you could use a (marker) interface.